# ToStringCreator() returns NULL value when the original string has special characters

Tags: java, spring, special-characters

My question is about that `ToStringCreator()` returns a `NULL` value when the original string has special characters.

I use Spring  "4.2.5.RELEASE" for my project.
I need to read some String values from a `.yml` file into my java classes.
I used the `ToStringCreator()` function when `@Override` the `public String toString() {}` method.

It handles most of the cases, including a string that has the period sign in it.
But it always returns `NULL` for the case that the URL for the `jdbck` connection  has all sorts of special characters like: `/ $ {variable}  ?  = &`.

I tried to put `\` in front of all these special characters.
And I also tried to use this function `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(mystr);` in the setter method.

But nothing worked.
Thanks so much in advance if you have any suggestions on this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Post a complete minimal example showing the issue. Tell us what you expect the example to produce as output, and what it does produce instead.

Comment: Can you please add the problem statements